# Why does Perl complain about "Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline"?

Tags: windows, perl

I am getting an error I do not understand. I am using File:Find to recurse a fylesystem on Windows using Activestate Perl 5.8.8 and trying to stat `$File::Find::name`; so I am not `stat`-ing a filename got from a text file scanning requiring `chomp`-ing or newline removing. I was unable to get file modification time, the `mtime` in:

```
my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,$atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat($File::Find::name);
```

so trying a

```
-s $File::Find::name
```

gives me the error:

> Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline

A typical file name found is *F01-01-10 Num 0-00000.pdf* but I get the same error even renaming in *E02.pdf*

Comment: why don't you try to chomp it and see. if it works, that means your files really have a newline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) if *any* file operation fails and the filename happens to contain a newline character, the warning "Unsuccessful  on filename containing newline" will be emitted.

The assumption is that, as you say, the filename has come from standard input or similar, and the user has forgotten to `chomp` the newline away. You might want to pass the string through `chomp` anyway, just to see if it works.

There is [some evidence](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/stat-broken-win32-activeperl-build-822) that `&CORE::stat` mtime might be broken with some combinations of OS patchlevel and ActiveState Perl versions - a suggested workaround is to use the [File::stat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::stat) module like so:

```
my $sb = stat($File::Find::name);
my $mtime = scalar localtime $sb->mtime;
```

...you might find File::stat's object representation to be more convenient than the list returned by `CORE::stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Even i got the same error while trying to delete a folder. i used chomp before using rmtree command. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same problem in my script and found my mistake to be when i created the file i tagged a date stamp to the end and forgot to chomp my $DATE variable before adding it to the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just ran into this myself with a hand built scalar. Scratched my head a bit until I realized I had included a time/date stamp in the filename. Chomp the date command and voila, problem resolved.

Comment: You do realise the ~exact same was already posted more than 2 years ago, right ?